# How to create maven dependency for a library containing of some 30+ jars

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on ADF application. In ADF, by default a web application will be created with 20 libraries. Each library will contain 2-30 jars included and they are referred from the JDeveloper middleware location which is physical location. Now we have a requirement to create a maven build script for the project. Till now we are using ant build scripts where in it will include the physical location path to refer each library.

Now when we try to create pom.xml, it is generating an empty pom and we need to include all these libraries in that. I found a way how to include a jar in maven repository but not a library. Can you please help me out in this.

Comment: In this context, what is a "library"? A zip-file?

Comment: You can try to reference this libraries as dependencies with "system" scope. See  [System dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies)

Comment: In Oracle ADF, Libray is a container which holds multiple jars. We will refer it as ADF Library(.libray).

Comment: Using system scope, we can refer only one Jar at a time. ADF application will contain plenty of dependent jars. Suppose further if we need to add a adf library, we need to add all the jars manually in pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up a more recent JDeveloper like JDev 12.2.1 and you'll have an option to create a pom from application that will add all the libraries for you.